# Web Scraping NBA Games Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I've been trying to write a code that extracts the names of the teams that play in that given day. This link (https://www.nba.com/scores) shows the games of the day.
Looking through the source code, I noticed that the names are contained in those div tags with class="score-tile__team-name" [Print Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoYAF.png).
I wrote this code, but it returns blank.
Thank you for the help!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get("https://www.nba.com/scores").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')

for div in soup.find_all('div', class_="score-tile__team-name"):
    print(div.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You acquire that data directly from the direct request.

```
import requests

jsonData = requests.get('https://data.nba.net/prod/v2/20200224/scoreboard.json').json()

for each in jsonData['games']:
    print ('%s @ %s' %(each['vTeam']['triCode'], each['hTeam']['triCode']))
```

**Output:**

```
MIA @ CLE
ATL @ PHI
MIL @ WAS
ORL @ BKN
NYK @ HOU
MIN @ DAL
PHX @ UTA
MEM @ LAC
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the "inspect element" tool, which shows you the page as it currently exists- and after a bunch of javascript is run. This is different than how the page is initially loaded. If you click `view source` you'll see the initial page that was loaded, before any javascript was run, which unfortunately does not contain the scores.

When you run `request.get` you're getting the initial page without the scores.

What you might want to do as a next step is open up the web tools, select `Network`, and then reload this page. Then look through what gets loaded to see if you can find the file that contains the scores.